# Docker: 502 Connection refused Error when connecting to Perl container from nginx

Tags: docker, perl, nginx

I'm building a simple docker environment on my own, including:

- PHP
- Perl
- Nginx

After building and running these containers, PHP is working well but accessing to .cgi or .pl returns 502 error.

my Dockerfile for perl is:

```
FROM perl:5.36
COPY perl/src /usr/share/nginx/html
```

setting file for nginx is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        # index          index.php index.html index.htm;
        fastcgi_pass   php-mt:9000;
        # fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ \.(cgi|pl)$ {
        # index          index.cgi index.html index.htm;
        fastcgi_pass   perl-mt:9001;
        # fastcgi_index  index.cgi;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '3'

services:
  php-mt:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile

  nginx-mt:
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./nginx/Dockerfile

  perl-mt:
    # restart: always
    tty: true
    expose:
      - 9001
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./perl/Dockerfile
```

`docker ps`command returns:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                NAMES
ce6f7d61cd4a   docker-mt_nginx-mt   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   20 minutes ago   Up 20 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   docker-mt_nginx-mt_1
62fd1c445dd2   docker-mt_perl-mt    "perl5.36.0 -de0"        27 minutes ago   Up 20 minutes   9001/tcp             docker-mt_perl-mt_1
c5ed035c144b   docker-mt_php-mt     "docker-php-entrypoi…"   3 hours ago      Up 20 minutes   9000/tcp             docker-mt_php-mt_1
```

and error is like:

```
nginx-mt_1  | 2023/03/21 06:37:13 [error] 30#30: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /perl.cgi HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.18.0.3:9001", host: "localhost"
nginx-mt_1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2023:06:37:13 +0000] "GET /perl.cgi HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

What I've done for this problem is:

- correcting exposing port of a perl container
- confirmation of working of .pl file inside perl container
- change permissions of .pl and .cgi files

Every suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: I tried using [official Dockerfile](https://github.com/perl/docker-perl/blob/c51cdfa8f849c8eebdeff2d0b9febe0c839ab77f/5.036.000-main-bullseye/Dockerfile) but it didn't work

Comment: I guess the cause might be missing of fastcgi for perl since i used php-fpm for php container. so i added fcgiwrap and spawn-cgi but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consuming almost a whole day, I found out solution.

- Installing serveral FCGI-related modules to perl container from CPAN
- Launching listening server using files written below

https://github.com/caribe/perl-fpm/tree/master